# Width of DIV dependent on width of window

Tags: css, html, width

I have the following problem. I am making this website you can see in the screenshot. It's basically a two rows - three columns Layout with div and css and everything is working fine so far. 
But the strippe above the "English"-div is supposed to always go to the right end of the brwoser, but i have no idea how I can achieve this. I've tried javascript but I can't get it to work.
Thanks in advance for your help.

The html code:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15902831/index_de.txt

Image of the website

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15902831/capture.png

Comment: Just learn about position attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery solution. Fully Tested.

The following solution uses jQuery to determine what the size of the strip should be, and then set it.
What's more it does it even when the user resizes their screen.

Just add the following to your `<head>`

> ```
> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   function resizeRedBar()
>   {
>           //determine what size the strip should be
>           var offset = $("#right_col").offset();
>           var windowWidth = $(window).width();
>           //now set the width of the red strip
>           $("#right_col_box_stripe_split").width(windowWidth - offset.left);
>   }
>   
>   $(document).ready(function()
>   {
>       //set size of red bar when page loads
>       resizeRedBar();
>       
>       $(window).resize(function()
>       {
>           //set size of red bar when window is resized
>           resizeRedBar();
>       });
>   });
> </script>
> ```

## Working Version

http://www.digitalbiscuits.co.uk/testbed/autosize_test

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. but for everyone who wants to use this also, it needs to be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: You don't need to specify the `"http://"` protocol, in fact it's better if you don't.
This is important if you are using `"https://"` and also want to take full advantage of the caching advantages of using a CDN hosted jQuery library.


You can read all about it here: http://bit.ly/Hg7zsQ

Comment: In my case it did not work without the http://

Comment: hmm, strange. I've had no issues using it this way on my various websites.
Well as long as it works, that's all that really matters I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS to the following.
I've tested it and it seems to work

> ```
> body
> {
> width: 100%;
> overflow-x: hidden;
> }
>
> #right_col_box_stripe_split {
> float: left;
> min-width: 201%;
> max-width: 1000%;
> height: 15px;
> background-color: darkRed;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, but now the website get's bigger. Overflow-x:hidden should cut the stripe off at the end of the page, but it doesn't. so the stripe is longer than the one at the top

Comment: hmm, strange. Well I have a javascript alternative if you're open to it.
It uses jQuery in fact

Comment: I've just added a new answer using javascript. You can see it working here: http://www.digitalbiscuits.co.uk/testbed/autosize_test

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:right;` from all the elements within `#right_col`. Using `float:right` in that situation prevents the divs from behaving like normal block elements, which is what you want in this case.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAxd7/1/) for a demonstration.

```
#right_col { 
  float: left; 
  background:lightgoldenrodyellow; 
  width:150px; 
  min-height:600px;
}

#right_col_box { 
  height:600px; 
}

#right_col_box_placeholder {
  height:485px;
}

#right_col_box_stripe_split {
  height:15px;
  background-color:darkred;
}

#right_col_box_bottom {
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
}
```